# jQuery not executing

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

So I have this code in my `script` tags:

```
$(function(){
  $("#news-link-1").click(runAccordion(1));
  $("#news-link-2").click(runAccordion(2));
  $("#news-link-3").click(runAccordion(3));
  $("#news-link-4").click(runAccordion(4));
  $("#news-link-5").click(runAccordion(5));
  $("#news-link-6").click(runAccordion(6));
  $("#news-link-7").click(runAccordion(7));
  $("#news-link-8").click(runAccordion(8));
  $("#news-link-9").click(runAccordion(9));
  $("#news-link-10").click(runAccordion(10));
  $("#news-link-11").click(runAccordion(11));
  $("#news-link-12").click(runAccordion(12));
})
```

But for some odd reason, I can only execute this function when there's only one row (condition) inside.

How can I execute this function with all the rows inside? Or perhaps I need an `if()` statement?

EDIT:
If I use an `if()` statement in a function, each next statement will override the previous one:

```
   $(function(){
   if ($("#news-link-1").click){
       runAccordion(1)
   }
   if ($("#news-link-2").click){
       runAccordion(2)
   }
});
```

Comment: Ever heard of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm soo noob at jQuery. OK then, what should I do? Alright why downvoting? I just asked a question that might look easy to you @downvoter but I need time to learn jQuery.

Comment: Do you think the title for the question is OK? You should learn basic not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the functions on the page load. You should pass the function without calling it using `()`, ie `$("#news-link-1").on('click', func)`, otherwise the returned value of the function is set as the event handler. Since here you want to pass an argument to the function, you should use another function:

```
$("#news-link-1").click(function() {
   runAccordion(1);
});
```

But I would suggest adding classes to the elements and using the `index` method:

```
var $links = $(".news-links").on('click', function() {
     var i = $links.index(this) + 1;
     runAccordion(i);
});
```

Now for selecting the matching target element in your `runAccordion` function you can use the `.eq()` method:

```
var $accordions = $('.accordions');
// ...
var $target = $accordions.eq(i);
```

Please note that both `index` and `eq` methods are zero-based!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your functions are all being executed at the time of page load, instead of when clicking on the element.

```
$("#news-link-1").click(runAccordion(1));
```

Instead these lines should look more like this:

```
$("#news-link-1").click(function(){
    runAccordion(1);
});
```

Notice the anonymous function wrapper in the second, this makes is so that the function you're attaching is one that is executing the runAccordion.  The first way executes runAccordion at run time, so if for example your runAccordion method returns "false", you would be essentially writing:

```
$("#news-link-1").click(false);
```

EDIT:

As a better suggested solution, maybe you could try something like this that's a little more DRY as the comments above suggested:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="news-link" data-news-id="1">Some news link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".news-link").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            runAccordion($(this).data("news-id"));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you aren't correctly passing a function reference as the `click` handler since `runAccordion(1)` calls the `runAccordion` function right away.

Without any markup change, you could do the following to stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
$(function(){
    $('[id^="news-link-"]').click(function () {
        runAccordion(+this.id.split('-').pop());
    });
});
```